# How to run url from cronjobs with javascript code in my php file

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I have url and i want to execute this url from cronjobs. in my php file there is javascript code to export highchart.

this is my code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
            var options = {

                title: {
                    text: 'Daily Chart',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                exporting: {
                    url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                    'A','B',
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'IDR'
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                series: [{
                    showInLegend: false,
                    name: 'Daily',
                    data: [
                        1,2
                    ]
                }]
            };
            var obj = {},
            exportUrl = options.exporting.url;
            obj.options = JSON.stringify(options);
            obj.type = 'image/png';
            obj.async = true;

            var link=$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: exportUrl,
                data: obj,
                dataType: 'html',
                context: document.body,
                global: false,
                async:false,

                success: function (data) {
                    var result=exportUrl+data;
                    return result;
                }
            }).responseText;
            $.ajax({
                        type: 'get',
                        url: 'http://webserver2/index.php/report/render?link='+link+'&id=1',
                        data: link,
                        success: function (data2) {
                            //alert(data2); 
                        }
                    });
});
</script>
```

If i execute it in my browser i will get file highcart.png to my server. But if i execute in cronjobs i get nothing. Any body know how to execute it with cronjobs??

Comment: You are asking to solve the wrong problem. What do you need in the end? It looks like you want to download or generate some kind of monitoring or stats image. (Sorry for sounding like Clippy.)

Comment: Yes, i want generate chart from highchart and then send chart to email report. I want to send an email with cronjobs. Can you help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a client-side language that runs from within a browser.
You can however use something like PhantomJS to run js from the server side. 
Look at: http://phantomjs.org/

**Edit:**

Download the necessary package from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Note that these are pre-compiled packages, we will assume you are using Linux.

You simply save the 'phantomjs' file in your filesystem somewhere (that you can access with crontab).

Save your javascript as a .js file extension.

Add a cron job like:

30 08 10 06 * /path/to/phantomjs javscriptfile.js

This will run 30 of June at 8.30am (You will need to schedule it when you want.)

Hopefully this should work as intended, although it does seem you are using jQuery functions so you might need to include the jQuery source code in your .js file.